# How do ik fk snap / switch in blender

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

I would like to know how I can do an ik / fk switch or snap system as some call it, so when I switch from fk to ik, ik is in the same position as fk.

Sample:https://youtu.be/SVwVAK6hj_8

Comment: Please create tags for more support